# how to import an ant build file inside other build file target

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have a very little knowledge about writing build files using ant targets.
the problem i am facilng is i want to have a build file which should import other ant build file if the given condition is satisfied.
For suppose here in the below code if ${myresult} is set to true then the postgreswebtest.xml should be used else mysqlwebtest.xml should be used.
So i tried  to achieve this with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<project name="webtest" default="build" basedir=".">
        <target name="build">
        <property name="DBTYPE" value="${arg0}" />
        <echo message="${DBTYPE}" />
        <condition property="myresult">
            <equals arg1="${DBTYPE}" arg2="postgres" />
        </condition>
        <echo message="${myresult}" />
        <if>
            <isset property="myresult"/>
            <then>
                <import file="postgreswebtest.xml" />
            </then>
            <else>
                <import file="mysqlwebtest.xml" />
            </else>
        </if>
    </target>
</project>
```

but when i execute this code getting the following error.

BUILD FAILED:
webtest.xml:21: import only allowed as a top-level task

Could someone please help me out with the solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant import doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681784/ant-import-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ant` ant task instead which acts as if it is imporing supplied build file. Refer to : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html for more details.

With `ant` you can provide default target to run as well.

With this approach it will conditional evaluate and import file inside your 'build' target.

```
<if>
            <isset property="myresult"/>
            <then>
                <ant antfile="postgreswebtest.xml" />
            </then>
            <else>
                <ant antfile="mysqlwebtest.xml" />
            </else>
 </if>
```